# Add old lead acids to parallel or replace them

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging, lead-acid

I have some old lead acids they are the same brand they bought at the same time SLA maintenance free 12 V @12 Ah.

I have measured their current capacities with a dummy load to about 3.6 Ah and 6 Ah. I have them in parallel so this should add up but they are kind of at the end of their life so I'm planning to buy 2 more 12 V @14 Ah.

The question is, is it worth to keep the old ones for the additional capacity in parallel or just completely throw them out and replace them with the new ones? If so, why?

My goal is of course to have the max Ah capacity.

Comment: It’s dead Jim. Replace them.

Comment: Old worn out lead acid batteries tend to have really high self discharge, which will also drain the good batteries.

Comment: The place you get the new batteries from should be happy to take the old ones for recycling.

Answer (score 1):

i have a solar home system that we purely use for trials and errors. Combining dead(or almost dead) battery with healthy one could affect the healthy battery and minimizing it life. It will unbalancing both battery, i must say. until now, none of our battery could live healthy more than 2 years..

Answer (score 0):

I agree to what is posted on [this forum](https://forum.solar-electric.com/discussion/15803/adding-a-new-lead-acid-battery-in-parallel-to-an-old-one) with the same question as yours:

Where westbranch said:

*Mixing batts of different ages is not recommended as they interact between themselves*

He also makes a suggestion of using a marine battery switch. That way you can leave the old battery charged up and on standby while you use the new battery for your initial demands of power. Whenever you need to, you can switch to the other (older) battery.

And Cariboocoot described some aspects of the issues that can appear as well:

*The problem is that a "perfectly good battery" is not the same as one that still has 100% of its capacity as the new one would. As a battery ages it inevitably loses capacity. The deeper it is discharged, the more cycles it is run through, and the time that passes all take their toll. The trouble is there is no practical way to determine how much the capacity has diminished.*

*Why it is bad to put an old and new battery together is the same as why it is bad to put two batteries of different capacity together (because that's what you've got): the charge will be wrong for one, the other, or most likely both. Too little for the higher battery, too much for the lower one. The greater this difference is the greater the risk of either frying the old battery (in a possible sudden failure) or cutting years off the life of the new one.*

*Another matter: do you have enough recharge ability to add more battery capacity? Chances are even if the system was properly designed to recharge one 160 Amp hour 12 Volt it can not do the same for two (320 Amp hours).*

*Since you are thinking of buying a new battery, needing to expand capacity, and inevitably will have to increase charge capacity it is time to re-evaluate. You probably would be better off buying one new battery of greater capacity (or two 6 Volt units) than adding another of the same on to the existing.*

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the charge and discharge currents never will be above the limits of the battery I see no issue if you connect them in parallel. ([Series would be bad](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574974/connecting-different-ah-lead-acid-batteries-in-series))

However keep in mind that this only is valid for lead batterie types not lithium.

Also keep @Klas-Kenny's comment in mind - if they are old/bad they will kill the new(er) ones too.

Source: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/429050/105090

Comment: When in doubt throw it out!